# function to get user IP address in Yii

Tags: yii

I'm trying to create a s shortcut to get user IP address, I created this function below in **protected/helpers/shortcut.php**

```
echo getIP();
function getIP()
{
    return CHttpRequest::getUserHostAddress();
}
```

i get this error because i set my php.ini to strict. and getUserHostAddress() is not a static function

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method CHttpRequest::getUserHostAddress() should not be called statically in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev/protected/helpers/shortcuts.php on line 97
::1
```

i tried

```
Yii::app()->request->userHostAddress;
```

but i get this error

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev/protected/helpers/shortcuts.php on line 97
```

any idea what i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Are you by any chance calling this function before the bootstrap has finished or for that matter in testing code or any other "non web context"?

Comment: Is see you put `echo getIP();` in the shortcuts.php file. So it will be run directly whenever this file is included. If this happens before the `CWebApplication::run()` function is called (normally form the index.php) you will get an error like this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try this:

```
Yii::app()->request->getUserHostAddress()
```

instead

```
Yii::app()->request->getUserHostAddress
```

with "()" it should work

Comment: Another way is:`Yii::app()->request->userHostAddress`

Answer (score 62):

In Yii2, use `Yii::$app->getRequest()->getUserIP()`

Comment: Great One. :) :) This answer only i was looking for. Thanku

Comment: even shorter: `Yii::$app->request->userIP;`.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to Yii2 (but may work in Yii 1.1 too). If you need the "X-Forwarded-For" IP instead of the Proxy, if your server is behind a reserve proxy, make the change the 'request' configuration on config/main.php as below:

```php
'request' => [
    'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
    'trustedHosts' => [
        '192.168.1.10', // The IP of the reverse proxy server
    ],
    'secureHeaders' => [ // The headers coming from reserve proxy
        'X-Forwarded-For',
        'X-Forwarded-Proto',
        'Front-End-Https',
    ],
],
```